# How to fix Gap install on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu

i have question about installing [Gap Software](https://www.gap-system.org/) on Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit). After command:

```
sudo apt install gap-core
```

all is ok. But after command

```
gap
```

i have error:

```
Error, Variable: 'DegreeOfMatrixGroup' must have a value not in any function at line 16 of ./pkg/irredsol-1.4/lib/matmeths.gi
```

If installation was done with [this instruction](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/blob/v4.9.2/INSTALL.md), all is ok.

How to fix it?

Comment: You haven't told us what you typed at the gap prompt to get that error... You might be better served reaching out the the folks at St. Andrews via the contact page (https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/contacts.html ).

Comment: I didn't type anything. I can't load GAP this way.